# VBA Excel Outlook Email Body Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have useform that sends emails automatically. I want to change the body of the email - some of it will be based on a cell with text so it could be dynamic and some will be fixed in the code. for now - in runs me an error of object required, i'll be thankful for help. 
I want every line in the body of the email to be separate.

```
Sub sendMail(ByVal mail As String, name As String, Msht As Worksheet, CCmail As Integer, CCperson As String)
    Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
    mailSub = Msht.Range("J2")
    mailbody = Msht.Range("L2")
    Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
    Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.add(mail)
    recptOL.Type = olTo
    If CCmail = 1 Then
        Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.add(CCperson)
        recptOL.Type = olCC
    End If
    tempPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.name
    With miOL
        .Subject = mailSub
        .Body = "bla bla" & "bla bla bla" & mailbody.Font.Underline & Msht.Range("M2").Font.Bold & Body = Msht.Range("N2")
        .Attachments.add (tempPath)
        .send

    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
    Set applOL = Nothing
    Set miOL = Nothing
    Set recptOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply HTML format to the body of the email:

```
Dim body_ As String
    body_= "<p> Hello </p>" & _
           "<p> This is a line </p>" & _
           "<p> This is another line </p>" & _
           "<p> This is yet another line. </p>"

.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & body_ & "</body></html>"
```

**Update**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sendMail(ByVal mail As String, name As String, Msht As Worksheet, CCmail As Integer, CCperson As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
    Set applOL = New Outlook.Application

    Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
    Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
    Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(mail)
        recptOL.Type = olTo

    Dim mailSub As String
        mailSub = Msht.Range("J2")

    Dim mailbody As String
        mailbody = "<p><u>" & Msht.Range("L2").Value & "</u></p>" & _
                   "<p><b>" & Msht.Range("M2").Value & "</b></p>" & _
                   "<p>" & Msht.Range("N2").Value & "</p>"

    If CCmail = 1 Then
        Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(CCperson)
        recptOL.Type = olCC
    End If

    Dim tempPath As String
        tempPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.name

    With miOL
        .Subject = mailSub
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & mailbody & "</body></html>"
        .Attachments.Add tempPath
        .send
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

Leave:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: wow thanks, but if i want some will be bold and some refer to specific text in cells.

Comment: For bold font you need to use the HTML bold tag `<b>text</b>`. As for the cell value use a simple string concatenation e.g. `"This is " & .Cells(1,1).Value.`

Comment: its not working for me when I change it to what I need, can you please write it for me as it should be?

Comment: in L2 something that i want to be a dynamic string with under line, M2 is a string that i want to do bold and N2 is just another line with no specific format and before that a regualar 2 strings for opening

Comment: See updated answer. You should check the `recptOL` field  -  it's set twice if `CCmail = 1`. FYI,  asking for "ready made" code will not help you learn. :)