# How can I build a Msg string with multiple lines and variables?

Tags: vba, string, outlook

I'm trying to make an action button in Access to build an email with specific text, a few variables, and multiple lines that looks like this once in Outlook:

[image: Outlook example]

The brackets in the picture indicate the variables.  I've tried a multitude of line codes, but I still can't get the variables or the text to look right.  Here's the code I'm trying:

```
Dim Msg As String
    
Msg = "Dear " & txt_OfficerName & ",<P>"
        <br /> Msg = Msg & "While searching for videos regarding " & Me.txt_CaseReportNumber ", I found that you had responded to the call, but your video was not tagged with the offense type and/or the CRN."
        Msg = Msg & "It is important to remember that no matter your involvement in a call, if you respond on a scene, your video is considered evidence and must be held as such."
        Msg = Msg & "You are required by policy to enter the appropriate offense in the Classify Tag and the 8-digit (no KC or dash [-]) CRN in the Case File Number field."
        Msg = Msg & "Not doing so creates a risk of destroying evidence which may affect future court cases."

vbCrLf Msg = Msg & "Thank you,"

vbCrLf Msg = Msg & "<strong>Digital Technology Section</strong>"

vbCrLf Msg = Msg & "Note: This is an automated message that was produced based on findings made by DTS while searching for videos in response to a prosecutor/attorney request, court order, or other citizen request."
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029588/vba-excel-outlook-email-body-formatting/47030397#47030397

Answer (score 0):

It depends what poperty you are going to set in the Outlook object model. The plain text message body (see the Body property) doesn't require any additional symbols, you can use standard constants, there are three different (constants) to add a line break.

- bNewLine
- vbCrLf
- vbLf

But if you need to format the message body your choice is the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property which requires a properly formatted HTML document. Here you can use any standard HTML tags like `<p>` and etc.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/ for possible options and tags.