# Vba code for drafting bulk email with attachments and hyperlink address as mentioned in the excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I am looking for the vba code where it drafts bulk email with text and hyperlinks in email body along with multiple attachments. I have the code which works fine as per details i need in email body. But i have mentioned hyperlink in excel and expecting the same email to generate along with hyperlink address, but unfortunately it gives plain text instead of hyperlink.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DraftOutlookEmails()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Email")

Dim i As Integer

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

'Set objects
Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim last_row As Integer

last_row = Sh.Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Read details from Excel sheet and draft emails

For i = 6 To last_row
'Create a new email item
    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
If Sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = Sh.Range("C" & i).Value

msg.To = Sh.Range("D" & i).Value
msg.CC = Sh.Range("E" & i).Value
msg.Subject = Sh.Range("F" & i).Value
msg.Body = Sh.Range("G" & i).Value

If Sh.Range("H" & i).Value <> "" Then
   msg.Attachments.Add Sh.Range("H" & i).Value
End If

If Sh.Range("I" & i).Value <> "" Then
   msg.Attachments.Add Sh.Range("I" & i).Value
End If

If Sh.Range("J" & i).Value <> "" Then
   msg.Attachments.Add Sh.Range("J" & i).Value
End If

If Sh.Range("K" & i).Value <> "" Then
   msg.Attachments.Add Sh.Range("K" & i).Value
End If

msg.Display
Sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "Done"

Next i

MsgBox "Email Draft is ready", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming the body is already HTML formatted, you need to set the body format  property as well: `msg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML`

Comment: Sorry Kostas, I am new to vba and in Excel I have mentioned the email body as text only and not html format. Could you pls help me here with the modified code which would work in my case

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029588/vba-excel-outlook-email-body-formatting/47030397#47030397

Answer (score 0):

The `Body` property contains a plain text which represents the message body:

```
msg.Body = Sh.Range("G" & i).Value
```

If you need to set up hyperlinks or any other formatting you need to build a well-formed HTML markup and then assign it to the `HTMLBody` property.

Also you may consider using the Word object model for dealing with message bodies. So, you can copy the required content in Excel and just paste it in the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information on that.